# How- to use a while loop to put a list of variable in a different TxT file in the command?

Tags: perl

it's a list of 3 sites and I just want to add every site on array @line. any help will be appreciated.

here is the text file

```
SF-Bosconero-Cluster

SF-Brampton-CA-Cluster
```

The output needs to be this... seems I'm almost there but I think is doing this going to another line.

mgmt_cli  install-policy policy-package "Site-Firewalls" access false threat-prevention true targets.1 "SF-Bosconero-Cluster
" targets.2 "SF-Brampton-CA-Cluster
"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd1;
my @cmdout=();
my $file = '/var/log/scripts/clusters_ips.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my @line = <$info>)  {
        my $var1 = shift @line;
        my $var2 = shift @line;

my $cmd;
chomp @line;
$cmd = "mgmt_cli install-policy policy-package \"Site-Firewalls\" access false threat-prevention true targets.1 \"$var1\" targets.2 \"$var2\" ";
#    print @line;
  #  print $info;
   print $cmd;
    last if $. == 3;
$cmd1 = `$cmd`;
@cmdout = ($cmd1);
}

close $info;
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try the following:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/var/log/scripts/clusters_ips.txt';
open (my $info, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";
chomp(my @clusters = <$info>);
close $info;
my $target_str;
for my $i (0..$#clusters) {
    my $cluster = $clusters[$i];
    $target_str .= " targets.$i \"$cluster\"";
}
say   "mgmt_cli install-policy policy-package \"Site-Firewalls\" "
    . "access false threat-prevention true " 
    . $target_str;
```

**Output:**

```
mgmt_cli install-policy policy-package "Site-Firewalls" access false threat-prevention true  targets.0 "SF-Bosconero-Cluster" targets.1 "SF-Brampton-CA-Cluster"
```

**Edit**

To run the previous generated string as a command you could try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/var/log/scripts/clusters_ips.txt';
open (my $info, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";
chomp(my @clusters = <$info>);
close $info;
my @targets;
for my $i (0..$#clusters) {
    my $cluster = $clusters[$i];
    my $tind = $i + 1;
    push @targets, "targets.$tind", "\"$cluster\"";
}
system 'mgmt_cli', 'install-policy', 'policy-package', '"Site-Firewalls"',
       'access', 'false', 'threat-prevention', 'true', @targets;
```

**Edit 2**:

To split the clusters into batches you can try something like this:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my $file = '/var/log/scripts/clusters_ips.txt';
    my $batch_size = 20;
    my @batches;
    {
        open (my $info, '<', $file) or die "Could not open $file: $!";
        chomp(my @clusters = <$info>);
        close $info;
        my @targets;
        @batches = split_into_batches($batch_size, @clusters);
    }
    for my $batch (@batches) {
        my @clusters = @$batch;
        my @targets;
        for my $i (0..$#clusters) {
            my $cluster = $clusters[$i];
            my $tind = $i + 1;
            push @targets, "targets.$tind", "\"$cluster\"";
        }
        system 'echo', 'mgmt_cli', 'install-policy', 'policy-package', '"Site-Firewalls"',
           'access', 'false', 'threat-prevention', 'true', @targets;
    }
}

sub split_into_batches {
    my $batch_size = shift;
    my @clusters = @_;
    my @batches;
    my $j = 1;
    my $idx = 0;
    for my $cluster (@clusters) {
        if ($j > $batch_size) {
            $j = 1;
            $idx++;
        }
        push @{$batches[$idx]}, $cluster;
        $j++;
    }
    return @batches;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!  one question to actually use the command "mgmt_cli install-policy policy-package \"Site-Firewalls\" " . "access false threat-prevention true " . $target_str; do I have to create a variable and then do 'cmd' ? or how would the scrip actually run that command?

Comment: @user1026398 You are welcome, see my updated answer for a suggestion

Comment: jumm for some reason I got this" Error: The parameters of install-policy command should be provided in pairs (key and value). You have provided an odd number of parameters which suggests that you are probably missing a parameter."

Comment: Can you try to run the `mgmt_cli` command directly from the terminal window without using the Perl script? Do you get the same error?

Comment: No it works. With the system why we have to split the command with commas “,”?

Comment: This syntax was used to avoid running the command through the shell and have to think about the quoting rules for the shell, see documentation here: https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system

Comment: I think the problem could be this parameter: 'access false'. It should be split in two separate parameters, right?

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect this

Comment: Thank @hakon one last question. I will have 200+ clusters if I want to run a limit of 10-20 but keep using the command when those 10-20 are done until the 200 are done. Would that be a While loop? I tried using last if $. == 2; just to see if it will worked but it stops at 2 clusters

Comment: *"keep using the command when those 10-20 are done"* I am not familar with the `mgmt_cli` command, how do you know when they are done?

Comment: I will get this message for that particular Batch :
"Policy installation - Site-Firewalls"  succeeded  (100%)
tasks:"
the goal is that when this is done the other batch of ex. 20 will continue

Comment: Ok.. what about the target indices? If you run in batches, should the `targets.1`, `targets.2` etc start from one again for the next batch?

Comment: yes correct it will start from one again.

Comment: See my updated answer for a suggestion..